# Django NoReverseMatch on URL

Tags: python, django, namespaces, url-routing

I'm running Django 1.4 w/ Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 12.04.

I have a website that I've added a URL namespace and am accessing it through the template `{% url common:utilities:index %}`.  Everything works fine locally.  I have a staging server that is failing (good thing I have a staging server  :)).

Error from the Django debug:

```
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value: u'utilities' is not a registered namespace inside 'common'

<a href="{% url common:utilities:index %}" class="responsive-tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Utilities">
```

I've double checked all the urls.py files and have verified the namespacing is correct - everyone in my team has verified this locally.

project urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^common/', include('common.urls', namespace='common')),
)
```

common urls.py:

```
utilitiespatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.ConversionUploadView.as_view(), name='index'),
)

urlpatterns = patterns('common.views',
    url(r'^utilities/$', include(utilitiespatterns, namespace='utilities')),
)
```

Obviously there are a lot more url routes than what I've put here.  This is just for the sake of the reader.

On the server I've cleared all the .pyc files.  I've restarted nginx.  I've cleared browser cache and opened in incognito.

After all that failed I actually got into the server shell and used the urlresolvers to verify the namespacing.

```
In [1]: from django.core import urlresolvers as u

In [2]: u.reverse('common:utilities:index')
Out[2]: '/common/utilities/'
```

I was thinking it might be an issue with the unicode character `u'utilities'`.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I was able to reboot the server and everything worked.  If anyone has an explanation into what happened I would gladly award them with a solution vote.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you wasn't restart uwsgi processes on server.

Comment: I was restarting all services.  I touched the wsgi file (which should force a restart).